# SSIS conditional split default output

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm having a hard time on using conditional split.

I have 2 conditions:

`Order | Output name             | Condition`

`1     | Status column completed                |(Status) == "Completed"`

`2     |Default         |            (Status) == "Completed" && (Status) == "Incomplete"`

on my first order, on the status column, all the completed status would go on my staging table and on my 2nd order regardless if status is completed or incomplete it will go to another table which serves as my raw table. as of now, using that conditions my 2nd order is not working. all the completed status are the only ones who goes to the correct table.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression on your `Default` output would filter out all rows because `Status` can't be both Completed and Incomplete for a given row.  More importantly, however, is that a conditional split only splits rows, if you want to send the full set of rows down one path, and a subset down another, you need to put a `Multicast` in the step ahead of your conditional split, and send one output of the multicast to your conditional split, and one to wherever you want all the records to go.

**Multicast**
allows you to send the full set of records down multiple paths (to multiple targets).

**Conditional Split** splits the set of records according to criteria you define, sending subsets of records down multiple paths.  Any records not caught in one of the defined conditions will be routed through a built in default-output. Like a `CASE` expression, each row coming into the split can only land in one output.

Your data flow would look something like this.

[image]

Comment: So you mean, after the conditional split I need to insert multicast and then the destination?

Comment: Before the conditional split, multicast sends the full set of rows to multiple downstream steps.  So multicast to conditional split with your 'Completed' criteria, and from the same multicast to wherever you wanted to send all the records regardless of status.

Comment: @HartCO No problem, you hit the points I would have made, just thought you needed a picture to tie it all together

Comment: Thank you for this, I have an idea now. Thanks.